# JOIN using IN with a sub query

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to do a join using a sub query with IN but I get an error "Comparison Operator IN not valid"

Is there a way to overcome this?

Here is my sql which doesn't work:

```
    SELECT
    SIZE,
    COUNT(SIZE)

FROM
  (SELECT ITEM,
        MIN(SZCUBC) AS CUBE
        FROM XXX.ITEM 
        JOIN XXX.ITEMA ON IAITEM = ITEM 
        LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD ON ITDHGT*ITDWTH*ITDDTH*QTY <= SZCUBC AND SIZE IN (SELECT SIZEB FROM DB.LOC WHERE BQTY>0 GROUP BY SIZEB) 
        WHERE IASOHQ >0 
        GROUP BY ITEM) t

LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD T1 ON SZCUBC = CUBE 

GROUP BY
    SIZE
```

I was using the below which works, but isn't dynamic...

```
    SELECT
    SIZE,
    COUNT(SIZE)

FROM
  (SELECT ITEM,
        MIN(SZCUBC) AS CUBE
        FROM XXX.ITEM 
        JOIN XXX.ITEMA ON IAITEM = ITEM 
        LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD ON ITDHGT*ITDWTH*ITDDTH*QTY <= SZCUBC AND SIZE IN ('TA','TB','TC','TD','TE','TF') 
        WHERE IASOHQ >0 
        GROUP BY ITEM) t

LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD T1 ON SZCUBC = CUBE 

GROUP BY
    SIZE
```

Comment: Which table does column `SIZE` belong to? BTW: it's always good to specify table references for all participating columns. It's may be hard to understand a query logic without this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per DB2 [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n338.html) on possibly a related error:

> The ON clause cannot contain a subquery.

Therefore consider a `WHERE` replacement:

```
...
  (SELECT ITEM,
        MIN(SZCUBC) AS CUBE
   FROM XXX.ITEM 
   JOIN XXX.ITEMA ON IAITEM = ITEM 
   LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD ON ITDHGT*ITDWTH*ITDDTH*QTY <= SZCUBC
   WHERE IASOHQ > 0 
     AND SIZE IN (SELECT SIZEB 
                  FROM DB.LOC 
                  WHERE BQTY > 0) 
   GROUP BY ITEM) t
```

Comment: It would be correct query rewrite, if the original query used `INNER JOIN DB.SIZECD`, but not  `LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing the IN clause with a JOIN clause

(and i removed  the group by  without aggreagtion function in you subquery with a distinct clause )

```
    SELECT
    SIZE,
    COUNT(SIZE)
FROM
  ( SELECT ITEM,
        MIN(SZCUBC) AS CUBE
        FROM XXX.ITEM 
        JOIN XXX.ITEMA ON IAITEM = ITEM 
        JOIN  (
          SELECT DISTINCT SIZEB 
          FROM DB.LOC 
          WHERE BQTY>0
        ) t2 ON t2.SIZEB = DB.SIZECD.SIZE
        LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD ON ITDHGT*ITDWTH*ITDDTH*QTY <= SZCUBC 
        WHERE IASOHQ >0 
        GROUP BY ITEM
        ) t
LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD T1 ON SZCUBC = CUBE 

GROUP BY  SIZE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `SIZE` belongs to `DB.SIZECD`.

```
LEFT JOIN 
(
DB.SIZECD C  
JOIN (SELECT SIZEB FROM DB.LOC WHERE BQTY>0 GROUP BY SIZEB) G ON G.SIZEB = C.SIZE
) ON ITDHGT*ITDWTH*ITDDTH*QTY <= SZCUBC
```

Instead of:

```
LEFT JOIN DB.SIZECD ON ITDHGT*ITDWTH*ITDDTH*QTY <= SZCUBC AND SIZE IN 
(SELECT SIZEB FROM DB.LOC WHERE BQTY>0 GROUP BY SIZEB)
```

We can't move the subselect with `DB.LOC` outside the `LEFT JOIN` to preserve the logic.